# Finding maximum power of resistor in 2 voltage source circuit

Tags: thevenin

I am trying to find the maximum power on R_L in the following circuit. I believe I need to use Thevenin's theorem but am not comfortable with it. I believe I need to find the equivalence of the circuit of everything on the left, but am not sure how to deal with the 2 batteries.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: You need kirchhoff's laws. All you need is the current through RL or the voltage across RL. After that, its your P=I^2R or P=V^2/R

Comment: Superposition!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving some hints since its been hours...

Continuing what @efox29 was saying, you could write two current loop equations (KCL).

Current one (\$i_{1}\$) going clockwise around the left loop and current two (\$i_2\$) going clockwise around the left loop, yields the following equations:

Left Loop

> \$6 -  10i_1 - 12 - 25i_1 - 15i_1 + 25i_2 = 0\$ Equation (1)

and Right Loop

> \$12 - R_Li_2 - 25i_2 + 25i_1 = 0\$ Equation (2)

Solve Equation 2 for \$i_1\$; substitute into Equation 1; solve for \$i_2\$ in terms or \$R_L\$; \$P = I_2^2R_L\$; solve for a Maximum.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

You can read about Thevenin's Theorem [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/).

Basically, it states that to find \$R_{Thevenin}\$ you short all voltage sources and open all current sources, then find the resistance looking in where the load was removed. That should make it very simple to get \$R_{Thevenin}\$

To find \$E_{Thevenin}\$ you remove \$R_L\$ and find the voltage at those terminals. You can use whatever method you prefer to solve for the voltage. As before you could write a KCL for the one loop. Solve for \$I\$ and find the voltage.

Draw your new circuit find the maximum power.

Comment: This is the first time on this site, I've seen the use of spoilers. Very nice. I think more people should use this for hw related questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no MAXIMUM power. There is only one power, and it is always the same. There are several ways to solve, including the Kirchoff Laws, though they all become the same, in the end. The answer, above, shows you how to solve for the one power, which is the maximum power, the minimum power, the average power, and "the power".

Comment: I think the OP wants to find the value of R_L that maximises power transfer.